# How to associate newly created SurfaceHolder to MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my code, I want to be able to temporarily hide (and subsequently show) a video. I am using a SurfaceView + MediaPlayer combination instead of the VideoView due to requirements. However, I am facing difficulties in getting video playback to occur as expected after I show the SurfaceView.

My code excerpts includes the following:

```
public void show() {
    if (mSurface != null) mSurface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void hide() {
    if (mSurface != null) {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) pause();
        mSurface.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mHolder = holder;
    openVideo();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(final SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // After this, the surface can't be used again
    mHolder = null;
}

private void openVideo() {
    if (mAssetPath == null || !mAssetPath.isEmpty() || mHolder == null) {
        // Not ready yet; try again later
        return;
    }

    // Pause music playback service
    Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
    i.putExtra("command", "pause");
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(i);

    if (mPlayer == null) {
        initializePlayer();
    } else {
        mPlayer.setDisplay(mHolder);
    }
}
```

Based on the above, when I call `hide()`, `surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder)` gets triggered. When I later call `show()`, `surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder)` gets triggered, which will call `openVideo()` and associate the player with the newly provided SurfaceHolder.

The above works as expected, and I believe this should be the correct process; however, when I call `mPlayer.start()`, I would hear the video's audio playing without any video and see the following error messages (which eventually causes the media playback to stop and complete, as noted by the `disconnect` logs):

```
10-23 11:29:42.775: E/MediaPlayer(4204): Error (1,-2147483648)
10-23 11:29:42.795: E/MediaPlayer(4204): Error (-38,0)
10-23 11:29:42.805: E/MediaPlayer(4204): Error (1,-2147483648)
10-23 11:29:42.810: V/MediaPlayer(4204): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
10-23 11:29:42.810: E/MediaPlayer(4204): error (1, -2147483648)
10-23 11:29:42.810: V/MediaPlayer(4204): callback application
10-23 11:29:42.810: V/MediaPlayer(4204): back from callback
10-23 11:29:42.825: E/MediaPlayer(4204): Error (1,-2147483648)
10-23 11:29:42.850: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4204): getCurrentPosition: 671668 (msec)
10-23 11:29:42.850: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4204): getCurrentPosition: 671668 (msec)
10-23 11:29:42.850: V/MediaPlayer(4204): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
10-23 11:29:42.850: E/MediaPlayer(4204): error (1, -2147483648)
10-23 11:29:42.850: V/MediaPlayer(4204): callback application
10-23 11:29:42.850: V/MediaPlayer(4204): back from callback
10-23 11:29:42.875: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4204): stop
10-23 11:29:42.875: V/MediaPlayer(4204): stop
10-23 11:29:42.875: E/MediaPlayer(4204): stop called in state 0
10-23 11:29:42.875: V/MediaPlayer(4204): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
10-23 11:29:42.875: E/MediaPlayer(4204): error (-38, 0)
10-23 11:29:42.875: V/MediaPlayer(4204): callback application
10-23 11:29:42.875: V/MediaPlayer(4204): back from callback
10-23 11:29:42.875: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4204): reset
10-23 11:29:42.875: V/MediaPlayer(4204): reset
10-23 11:29:42.900: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4204): release
10-23 11:29:42.900: V/MediaPlayer(4204): setListener
10-23 11:29:42.900: V/MediaPlayer(4204): disconnect
10-23 11:29:42.910: V/MediaPlayer(4204): destructor
10-23 11:29:42.910: V/MediaPlayer(4204): disconnect
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before and found a workaround? Or would the only option be to create a new MediaPlayer as well?

Comment: http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/custom-android-media-controller. check this if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am not having issues with media controller. I am trying to temporarily hide SurfaceView, then bringing it back and continuing the previously instantiated video playback on it.

Comment: Just a quick thought... Have you tried TextureView instead of SurfaceView? It depends on what version you are targeting as to whether you can use it, but it's not as volatile and could help with debugging.